# How to adjust column width in Linux command output

Tags: text-processing, grep, columns

When I used this command on Red Hat Linux

```
/usr/sbin/ss -i
```

I get the following output below:

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                            Local Address:Port                                                Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      0                                                    <IP_ADD:PORT>                                                  <IP_ADD:PORT>
         ts sack wscale:2,2 rto:204 rtt:4.5/6.5 ato:40 cwnd:3
ESTAB       0      0                                                    <IP_ADD:PORT>                                                  <IP_ADD:PORT>
         ts sack wscale:2,2 rto:213 rtt:13.875/18.5 ato:40
ESTAB       0      0                                                    <IP_ADD:PORT>                                                  <IP_ADD:PORT>
         ts sack wscale:2,2 rto:201 rtt:1.875/0.75 ato:40
ESTAB       0      0                                                    <IP_ADD:PORT>                                                 <IP_ADD:PORT>
         ts sack wscale:9,2 rto:201 rtt:1.875/0.75 ato:40
```

Whenever I try to pipe `grep` to that command `ex`:

```
/usr/sbin/ss -i | grep <SOME_IP_ADD>
```

I have this output

```
ESTAB      0      0              <IP_ADD:PORT>           <IP_ADD:PORT>
ESTAB      0      0              <IP_ADD:PORT>           <IP_ADD:PORT>
ESTAB      0      0              <IP_ADD:PORT>           <IP_ADD:PORT>
```

Notice that grep didn't include this:

```
ts sack wscale:2,2 rto:204 rtt:4.5/6.5 ato:40 cwnd:3
```

because its on another line. So how do I adjust the column width whenever I use this command or other Linux commands for that matter. So that the output will not word-wrap or go to the next line? Are their better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your grep has it, try the `-A1` option.

It looks like it is not a case of wrapping, but that the entry is on a separate line.

```
/usr/sbin/ss -i | grep -A1 <SOME_IP_ADD>
```

Look at `Context Line Control` in `man grep`.

An alternative would be to use

```
-P Perl-regex 
-z suppress-newline
-o print only matching
```

as in:

```
ss -i | grep -Pzo '.*IPADDRESS.*\n.*'
```

Then you won't get the surrounding dashes which context gives.

---

An alternative could be sed:

```
sed -n '/IPADDRESS/{N;p}'
# Or joining the two lines by:
ss -i | sed -n '/IPADDRESS/N;s/\n/ /p'
```

awk:

```
awk '/IPADDRESS/{print; getline; print}'
# Or as joined lines:
awk '/IPADDRESS/{printf "%s ", $0; getline; print}'
```

Comment: Hey thanks sukminder your suggestions worked!!! But I don't know where to give the points though since both of you answered at the same time :s

Comment: Yes, – that can be a dilemma but thanks. I'll up-vote @drs ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `ts sack ...` line is placed below the `ESTAB ...` line because that is how `ss` always formats this type of information.  It's not being line-wrapped.  You can include both lines in `grep` by using the `-A1` flag:

```
ss -i | grep <IP ADDRESS> -A1
```

You can combine each match to one line by passing it through a `sed` command:

```
ss -i | grep <IP ADDRESS> -A1 | sed '/^--$/d;N;s/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: Hey thanks, -A1 works perfectly. I don't know where to give the points though since both of you answered at the same time :s

Comment: Ps. That sed command does not works as intended (I believe) because of the dashes added by grep in context mode. Try `sed '/--/d;N;s/\n/ /'` instead.

Comment: @Sukminder, I missed those.  Nice catch.

Comment: Ah. or `sed -e '/^--$/d;N;s/\n/ /'` would probably be a good idea.

Comment: i'll just upvote drs coz sukminder already have a lot of points lol. thanks again